# $wpdb->get_results: How return all data from a single column?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's my query:

```
global $wpdb; 
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT NAME_MYCOLUMN FROM NAME_TABLE");
foreach ( $result as $row ) 
{
    $data = "$row-> NAME_MYCOLUMN|";  
}
$val = "'/\b($data)\b/i'"; 
echo $val;
```

I get this:

```
'/\b(word1|)\b/i'
```

where `word1` is the last value.

Instead, I would like to have this:

```
'/\b(word1|word2|word3|word4|.......)\b/i'
```

My goal is to get all the column values not only the last.

---

Thank you all, but the three solutions proposed do not work well. The result is the same :(
In my table there are over one hundred words but I have:

```
'/\b(word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|word7|word8|
```

Is there a solution ?

EDIT

I have understand where's the error. I have accidentally added into the database as a word with ID9 < word9 and this (<) has broken the code after the word with ID 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`$wpdb->get_col`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column) to fetch an array of values. Then use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join them with a `|`.

```
global $wpdb; 
$result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT NAME_MYCOLUMN FROM NAME_TABLE");
$data = implode('|', $result);
$val = "'/\b($data)\b/i'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb; 
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT NAME_MYCOLUMN FROM NAME_TABLE");
$val = "'/\b("; 
foreach ( $result as $row ) 
{
  $val .= "$row-> NAME_MYCOLUMN|";
}
$val .= ")\b/i'"; 

echo $val;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT` to return all the rows in a single row

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "
     SELECT 
     GROUP_CONCAT(NAME_MYCOLUMN SEPARATOR '|') as NAME_MYCOLUMN 
     FROM NAME_TABLE
");
```